# TypeDoesNotMatch - BigDecimal to Long on .GENERATED_KEYS?

Tags: scala, anorm

I'm trying to perform an insert but i'm receiving this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: TypeDoesNotMatch(Cannot convert 7: 
 class java.math.BigDecimal to Long for column ColumnName(.GENERATED_KEYS,Some(GENERATED_KEYS)))
```

What is wrong with my insert?

```
  def insertImportedFile(bean:Bean) : Option[Long] = {
    DB.withConnection("conn") { implicit connection =>
      val sqlQuery = SQL(
        """
        INSERT INTO Persons (name, group, dateCreated) 
        VALUES ({name}, {group}, {dateCreated}, )
        """
      ).on(
          "name" -> bean.name,
          "group" -> bean.group,
          "dateCreated" -> new Date
        ).executeInsert()
      return sqlQuery
    }
  }
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: What is your `PRIMARY KEY` ?

Comment: It's a key generated from SQL Server (auto identity = true)..i think i need to do something to get return (i.e. 8)  as BigDecimal instead Long

Comment: Is the type `DECIMAL` in the db? If so, try `executeInsert(scalar[BigDecimal].singleOpt)`